# execute .jar file from another Java program

Tags: java, jar, java.util.scanner

I'm wondering how can I execute a Java program when I enter input into another Java program? Like the program I'm running can accept user input and based on that input it searches for a file with the same name and executes it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible although when executing a `.jar` file, you may receive some errors when attempting to launch the jar if it isn't a frame or some kind of desktop application-type thing. You could accept user input with a scanner, for example, asking the user to define a path to a `.jar` file they wish to execute.

Here is an example of running a `.jar` file:

```java
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/Path/To/File"));
```

In the `/Path/To/File` part, you could just use user input.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely check!